# Rundeck triggers a scheduled job twice

Tags: scheduling, jobs, rundeck

We have wto rundeck instances in cluster. rundeck-config.properties in both the instances has below property

> rundeck.clusterMode.enabled=true

and rundeck.server.uuid value in framework.properties is same in both the instances.

So we want one of the instance to trigger scheduled jobs, but right now both the instances are triggering it and every job is running twice. The main reason we configured the cluster is to have a backup, if one of the instance goes down the other instance should trigger the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `rundeck.server.uuid` is unique for each server.

You can generate a unique by running the `uuidgen` command on a Linux server.